Problems with react hooks on media queries
I am developing a react hook that checks if the user is in a reduced-motion browser, but I am having trouble with the window object being undefined by default. Until now I only got to this:
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

/**
 * Checks if the browser is running on reduced motion
 * @returns true if the browser is running on reduced motion
 */
const usePrefersReducedMotion = (): boolean => {
  const windowRef = useRef<Window | null>(null);
  const [prefersReducedMotion, setPrefersReducedMotion] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPrefersReducedMotion(
      windowRef.current!.matchMedia("(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce").matches
    );
  }, [window]);

  return prefersReducedMotion;
};

export default usePrefersReducedMotion;

By trying I mean that the window object is still undefined, even after the useEffect.


What is the ref doing for you here?  You assign it null, and never change the value... 2. what do think the useEffect is doing?  3. Probably you should be checking window, and dispense with the ref altogether.


This code snippet was a previw of the actual code, I deleted a bunch of lines and deleted the use of the ref... oops

Remember how useEffect works, the array dependencies cannot listen to a dom change, even with ref; here you listen to the window object which won't trigger any rendering nor effect. It might looks like it works but you'll get an unexpected behaviour.
For you issue, not need for useRef though. When useEffect function run, the dom is kind of already mounted, means the window object exist inside your useEffect.

useEffect(() => {
    //just to make sure the window object is available
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        setPrefersReducedMotion(
            window.matchMedia("(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce").matches
        );
    }

}, [])



I actually thought that the dependency array was to monitor object changes lol. Your answer worked exactly how I wanted thanks!!

@Fernando It does monitor changes, but only when a React render is triggered. The reason props and states can be used as dependency without issue, is because changing a prop or a state will trigger a new render. Within this render a change in dependencies is detected, causing it to run the useEffect callback after the render is complete. If you place some global variable within the dependency array a change will most likely not trigger a React render. Meaning that the useEffect callback waits until something else triggers the render, at which point it detects a change.

Another issue with window in the dependency array is that dependencies are compared based on object identity using Object.is(). The window object is never assigned a new identity, but has its properties mutated instead. Because window is never actually replaced with a new object Object.is(old_window, new_window) will always return true. Similar to how post = { title: 'hello world' }, post.title = 'hello friend' will not be detected as change. It still refers to the same object.

@3limin4t0r, i saw you edited my answer, actually there's a reason of the use of typeof window !== 'undefined'  instead of just window, if you build it vite react or simple CRA, it won't throw any error. But if you built this in nextjs app (not typescript), this prone to build error as no window object is  defined anywhere on serverside.

@riv0manana Are you sure this results in an error for nextjs? Normally everything that is not part of the initial component render should not be executed on the server. Since useEffect callbacks are executed after the initial render they should be executed on the client even if the component is a server component. Server components sends the output HTML to the client and is then hydrated, after that the callbacks/event handlers/etc are executed on the client. Meaning that as long as you don't refer to window during the initial component render it shouldn't be a problem.

@3limin4tor, might be one of nextjs version, but i'm talking from experience with one of our app. Because you're right, everything in useEffect should taken as mounted but don't know somehow on build we got issue about it
